# Merging to array and getting error

Tags: php, arrays, json

Here is what i am doing, Storing values from a form to array and then storing that array into a file (**array.jason**).

```
    if (isset($_POST['addEntity'])) {
    $values = array_values($_POST);
    print_r($values);
    unset($values[1]);
    var_dump($values);
    $file_values = json_decode(file_get_contents('array.json'), true);
    array_combine($file_values,$values);
    file_put_contents("array.json",json_encode($values),FILE_APPEND);
}
```

Now, when i try to merge array from file ($file_values) to an array which i get from submit ($values) i am getting this error or warning :(

> Warning: array_combine() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given
>   in **C:\Users\tej\PhpstormProjects\Final Year Project\index.php on
>   line 9**

Comment: Your `json_decode()` failed an return NULL, that's why `null given`. Tell us the output of: `json_last_error_msg()` and show your json data. Your json isn't valid. (btw: assigning the return value of `array_combine()` would be good)

Comment: array.jason have ["tej"]["tej"]["tej"] 
every time a submit a value new array store in array.jason but i want one array which store value when ever i submit the form

Comment: This is not valid json. Wherever you save that data into your file you are doing it wrong.

Comment: what are you waiting for !! tell me the right way then !! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are a few things wrong in your code which got you a few errors. First I will show you how you can fix your code and second what went wrong and what happened.

So to fix your code you have to assign the return value of `array_combine()` back to `$values` and just overwrite the file, since you added the new data to the old decoded one, e.g.

```
if (isset($_POST['addEntity'])) {
    $values = array_values($_POST);
    unset($values[1]);

    $file_values = json_decode(file_get_contents('array.json'), true);
    $values = array_combine($file_values,$values);
    file_put_contents("array.json", json_encode($values));
}
```

---

But what happened without that assignment and the appending of the file is. You just encoded your new data into JSON and appended it to your file. Means you created:

```
[DATA 1]
[DATA 2]
[DATA ...]
```

So when you tried to decode it again, all encoded data combined weren't valid anymore, even though they are as a single line they aren't as entire file. Which then lead `json_decode()` return `NULL`, since it wasn't valid JSON, and finally you tried to combine NULL with an array which got you a PHP error.

Comment: Okay Got it !! Thank you

Comment: @GurtejSingh You're welcome.(Also, make sure you delete the invalid stuff first before you use the fixed code)